# SQL Oracle, select remove text and format date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 columns:

```
   Name         Date
name1@group     43328                 
name1@group     43329                 
name2@group     43330
name2@group     43331                 
name3@group     43332                 
name3@group     43333
```

This is what the end result should be, **name** from column Name (without @group) and the maximum **number** from column Date:

```
Name        Date
name1       43329                 
name2       43331                 
name3       43333
```

But, the maxim number in Data format (the column Date):

```
Name        Date
name1       17-Aug-2018                 
name2       19-Aug-2018                 
name3       21-Aug-2018
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where's "name2" coming from?

Comment: How did you convert "43329" to "17-Aug-2018"? Days since Jan 1, 1900 AD?

Comment: sorry, i edited now the post :)

Comment: in excel format 43329 = 17/09/2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regexp_substr()` is a simple way to extract the email.  The date arithmetic is pretty simple.  So:

```
select regexp_substr(email, '[^@]+', 1, 1) as email, max(date '1900-01-01' + dte - 1)
from t
group by regexp_substr(email, '[^@]+', 1, 1) ;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/KLYRGF12154) is a rextester.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `instr()` and `substr()` to extract the name without the group.

```
SELECT substr("name", 1, instr("name", '@') - 1) "name",
       to_date('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + max("date") - 1 "date"
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY substr("name", 1, instr("name", '@') - 1);
```

Another one is to use `regexp_substr()`.

```
SELECT regex_substr("name", '^[^@]+') "name",
       to_date('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + max("date") - 1 "date"
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY regex_substr("name", '^[^@]+');
```

It has the advantage, that it uses the whole string as name, shouldn't there be any `'@'` in it as to compared to the first yielding an empty string (i.e. `NULL` in Oracle) in such a case. Regular expression are likely more resource hungry though. You could also try to check for the occurrence of an `'@'` and only apply the `substr()` on the name, if there's an `'@'` in it.

---

Edit:

If those numbers are from Excel, you must subtract one day, as [Excel falsely treats 1900 as a leap year](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year).

Comment: To convert the [numeric] "date" column to a bona fide date you can use: `(date '1900-01-01' + "date") as my_date`